# SQL query with a complex SELECT query from multiple tables, need NULL value

Tags: sql-server, select

The whole query is quite complex and embeds a lot of data that is retrieved from 5 different tables with different references. I'm almost there and now it's just a CASE command that not does what I want.
The problem is in the "Area_Numbers" column. The entries that have no value get parentheses instead of "NULL"
[Area_Numbers column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InqrH.png)

The line that makes this column is like this, and it is the "CONCAT" command that creates the unwanted parantheses:

```
CONCAT('(',(STRING_AGG((CASE WHEN LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) = 20 AND UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN SUBSTRING(AccessLevels.Name,LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) + 1, (LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('>', AccessLevels.Name)))-LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name)))-1)) ELSE NULL END), ')(')), ')') AS Area_Numbers
```

I then try adding another CASE condition at the beginning to only include the poses that have a value

```
CASE WHEN UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN (CONCAT('(',(STRING_AGG((CASE WHEN LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) = 20 AND UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN SUBSTRING(AccessLevels.Name,LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) + 1, (LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('>', AccessLevels.Name)))-LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name)))-1)) ELSE NULL END), ')(')), ')')) ELSE NULL END AS Area_Numbers
```

It then gives the following error message:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Column 'UserCustomFieldGroupData.CustomFieldID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I then try to add the variable "max" at the beginning, as it solved similar errors I had before and you don't need to add the column in `GROUP BY`

```
max(CASE WHEN UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN (CONCAT('(',(STRING_AGG((CASE WHEN LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) = 20 AND UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN SUBSTRING(AccessLevels.Name,LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) + 1, (LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('>', AccessLevels.Name)))-LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name)))-1)) ELSE NULL END), ')(')), ')')) ELSE NULL END) AS Area_Numbers
```

It instead gives this error message:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I then go into another strategy and move the "CONCAT" part to after "THEN" in the string to only activate it on the lines where the CASE question is correct:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) = 20 AND UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN CONCAT('(',(STRING_AGG((SUBSTRING(AccessLevels.Name,LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) + 1, (LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('>', AccessLevels.Name)))-LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name)))-1))), ')(')), ')') ELSE NULL END AS Area_Numbers
```

This results in all the sources in the row needing to be included in `GROUP BY`:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Column 'AccessLevels.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Column 'AccessLevels.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Column 'UserCustomFieldGroupData.CustomFieldID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

If I complete in this mode with MAX at the beginning, the error message that it is not possible to use an aggregation function on an already aggregated value comes up

```
max(CASE WHEN LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) = 20 AND UCD.CustomFieldID LIKE '1' THEN CONCAT('(',(STRING_AGG((SUBSTRING(AccessLevels.Name,LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name))) + 1, (LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('>', AccessLevels.Name)))-LEN(LEFT(AccessLevels.Name, CHARINDEX ('<', AccessLevels.Name)))-1))), ')(')), ')') ELSE NULL END) AS Area_Numbers
```

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: I think your query would become more easy to read if you would use windowing and/or subqueries, and that could at the same time solve your problem

Comment: If is much difficult you can also put the `CASE` in front of `CONCAT`, like this `CASE CONCAT... = () THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT`

Comment: If the main problem is that value with () must be considered as NULL then use NULLIF function: NULLIF(Area_Numbers, '()')

Comment: This indicates that you use an aggregation in your query - please post the whole query nstead of a single row.

Comment: Proper sample data and expected results as *text* not images, as well as your *full* query, would help immensely

Answer (score 0):

I found your main problem is struggling with value '()' which is preferred to be null. Although it is more efficient to avoid setting this value in initial state of INSERT/UPDATE and control the value, But anyway in your case use `NULLIF` function.
Example with your code:

```
NULLIF(Area_Numbers, '()')
```

When the values of first and second expression are equal then output is `NULL`,
other wise the first expression will be returned.